# jQuery to limit number of http requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using ['snap widget'](http://snapwidget.com/) to pull a number of instagram photos into a page. However, it pulls 25 images in (which is a lot of http requests). I want to limit it to 7, but there is no setting to do this. I was wondering if there was a way to halt the calls of the widget by writing some jQuery or Javascript. It uses an iframe.

[Here is an example of the widget](http://snapwidget.com/sc/?h=YW1hemluZ3xpbnwxNTB8M3wzfHxub3w1fG5vbmV8fHllc3xubw==&ve=030815&ispreview=1)

Comment: According to their official Support Center http://support.snapwidget.com/customer/portal/questions/4063046-scrolling-widget-limit-">, you can edit the limit of photos displayed in the scrolling widget with the Pro widget. Sure there are many ways to make you own dirty code but those kind of HACKS not allowed to be shared here. You can look for another widget or find any open source one then try to add you custom functionalities.

Comment: I might just write my own. Also, hacks are not allowed to be shared?

Comment: Very well, write your own :) Regarding hacks, Stackoverflow never stops the spread of knowledge but without hurting others. Your question would be valid if you asked for general knowledge without mentioning that widget.
See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284463/are-hacking-questions-allowed and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262656/should-questions-about-programming-viruses-and-malware-be-allowed

Comment: in the end wrote my own using this: https://github.com/ryancw/instagram-scroll/blob/master/README.md